# Valores não ficam na coluna certa na tabela

Tags: php

[image: erro]

```
<?php
        $listar = new FuncionarioDAO();
        $resultTudo = $listar->listar();

        $results = new FuncionarioDAO();
        $results = $results->retornaEmpresa();

        while($row = $resultTudo->fetch_assoc()) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row['id']?></td>
                <?php
                foreach($results as $values) {?>
                    <td><?php if($values['id'] == $row['id_empresa']){echo $values['nome']; break;}?></td>
                <?php }?>
                <td><?= $row['nome']?></td>
                <td><?= $row['sobrenome']?></td>
                <td><?= $row['telefone']?></td>
                <td><a class="label label-warning" href="<?= "funcionario-atualizar?x=".$row['id'];?>">editar</a></td>
                <td><a href="<?= "funcionario-remover?x=".$row['id'];?>" class="label label-danger">remover</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }if($resultTudo->num_rows == 0){
            print("<h3 class='btn btn-warning'>Nenhum produto cadastrado ainda</h1>");
        }?>
```

Comment: Tem um foreach lá no meio da linha da tabela que não faz o mínimo sentido. E seria legal trocar esse monte de abre e fecha PHP por "echo", assim facilita ler o código. Outra coisa, usar `<?=` é pedir pra sua aplicação funcionar só num lugar. Isso é meio complicado.

Comment: Existe uma tabela funcionario q se relaciona com uma tabela empresa, a tabela funcionario tem o id da empresa ai eu coloquei pra lista o nome da empresa. Mas ficou assim a tabela.

Comment: select * from funcionario join empresa

Comment: Fiz pra percorrer o resultado até encontrar o valor e imprimir.

Comment: Poderia fazer `$results[0]['nome']` e tirar o `foreach` por completo, já que quer pegar só um resultado, mas de qualquer forma poderia trazer esse campo de um JOIN, com uma query só. Dá uma olhada na tabela no geral, deve ter um `<tr>` com `<td>` a mais que outros `<tr>`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

um remendo no seu código é esse:

```
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['id']?></td>
            <td>
            <?php
               foreach($results as $values) {
                  if($values['id'] == $row['id_empresa']) {
                     echo $values['nome'];
                     break;
                  }
               }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td><?= $row['nome']?></td>
            <td><?= $row['sobrenome']?></td>
            <td><?= $row['telefone']?></td>
```

Mas isso é só remendo, pois o código está demais bagunçado. Provavelmente já tem erros anteriores.

Outra coisa. O ideal é seu código começar com `<?php` lá em cima, e terminar com `?>` no final. Esse negócio de abrir e fechar o PHP a toda hora no meio do código não existe. Ou você usa echo, ou então feche e abra de novo o PHP só em blocos muito grandes de HTML.

### Outra solução:

Aqui já tem outra técnica: fazemos um *array* com as empresas todas, e buscamos por ID ao fazer a tabela, tirando o `foreach` das empresas do meio do outro loop (e de quebra, rodando uma vez só):

```
<?php
    $listar = new FuncionarioDAO();
    $resultTudo = $listar->listar();

    $results = new FuncionarioDAO();
    $results = $results->retornaEmpresa();

    $empresas = array();
    foreach( $results as $values ) {
       $empresas[ $values['id'] ] = $values['nome'];
    }

    while($row = $resultTudo->fetch_assoc()) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['id']?></td>
            <td><?= $empresas[ $row['id_empresa'] ]?></td>
            <td><?= $row['nome']?></td>
            <td><?= $row['sobrenome']?></td>
            <td><?= $row['telefone']?></td>
            <td><a class="label label-warning" href="funcionario-atualizar?x=<?= $row['id']; ?>">editar</a></td>
            <td><a href="funcionario-remover?x=<?= $row['id']; ?>" class="label label-danger">remover</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }if($resultTudo->num_rows == 0){
        print("<h3 class='btn btn-warning'>Nenhum produto cadastrado ainda</h1>");
    }?>
```

Comment: Tá. Vou usar assim agora. Mas por que estava com aquele erro?

Comment: Você estava criando um monte de TD dentro do foreach. Ia criando TD vazio até chegar no ID da empresa. Mas é sério, seu código nem devia precisar disso. Tinha que ser só `<td><?= $row['nome_empresa']?></td>`, igual o resto. Bastaria no lugar do select * você por nome certo nas coisas, e por um ON no join.

Comment: Ahhhhhh era pra ter colocado antes do foreach. Erro de atenção :(

Comment: Nao era pra ter foreach nenhum. Era pra ser só `select id, empresa.nome AS nome_empresa, funcionario.nome AS nome, sobrenome, telefone from funcionario join empresa on id=id_empresa`. Ou coisa do tipo. E no lugar do foreach bastaria `<td><?= $row['nome_empresa']?></td>`

Comment: É, só que eu estou usando uma query pra tudo. Ai precisava do foreach.

Comment: Falta de usar o JOIN corretamente. Sério, se vc aprender a usar, vai ajudar seu código. O Join com clausula ON ja vai trazer apenas a empresa certa, sem foreach nenhum.

Comment: Mas seu eu colocar como tu disse, msmo assim precisaria de um foreach pra percorrer e listar.

Comment: Nao sei daonde vc tirou essa idéia, mas nao precisaria mesmo. O ON do join serve pra voce escolher qual vai ser o critério de escolha.

Comment: Não? Tem como colocar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Veja aqui sobre joins. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/70 - O que muda no seu caso é que no lugar de profissao vc vai usar empresa. E provavelmente é o LEFT JOIN que te interessa, pois vai mostrar todos os nomes (tabela A), tendo ou nao empresa (tabela B). Uma vez feito o JOIN, pro PHP é como se fosse uma tabela só.

Comment: @PauloCosta veja um outro jeito de fazer, sem Join e sem foreach, na resposta

Comment: Tá! Vou olhar lá Mestre Supremo.

Comment: ¬¬  De novo essa, não... hehehe.